# Process.WaitForExit does not return with ALT+F4

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am writing a WPF launcher application for multiple little Unity3D and Unreal projects that reads the exit code from a hub application (also Unity) to start other projects depending on the received exit code.

Unfortunately some of those little projects have no "clean exit" implemented and need to be killed via `ALT+F4` which, in turn, is not registered by my launcher app for some reason.

**The exit code part is not relevant for the problematic projects.** I only use the exit codes for the hub application. Launching them from the hub app works just fine and if they have some means of exit implemented my launcher works like a charm.

I am using `WaitForExit` with no timeout because the applications run indefinitely if the user does not exit.

```
private static Process currentRunningProcess;

public static void StartApp(string applicationPath)
{
    if (currentRunningProcess != null) return;
    currentRunningProcess = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(applicationPath)
    };
    currentRunningProcess.Start();
}

//this function is used both for the hub app and for the little projects to
//avoid having two functions that basically do the same
//the exit code is only used for the hub app and ignored for anything else
public static int GetExitCode()
{
    currentRunningProcess.WaitForExit();
    var exitCode =  currentRunningProcess.ExitCode;
    currentRunningProcess = null;
    return exitCode;
}
```

Am I missing something or is this supposed to work this way? If the second case is true, how can I improve my implementation to also register `ALT+F4`ed applications?

(Implementing a clean exit for the the little projects is unfortunately not possible since some of them are commisions from third party providers where I do not have the source code available)

Comment: make "implement a clean exit routine" mandatory, for any project you'll provide trough your little Launcher.

Comment: @Mischa I did not know that I needed it until I started working on that launcher last week. I will do that for future projects for sure, but I also need my current projects working with it.

Comment: Check task manager - have the processes actually gone or have they just closed their window?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the tip! It seems like the process is still running in the background. It also only happens with Unreal projects. I tested a few Unity applications and it worked just fine even when `Alt+F4`ing

Comment: Okay I can confirm that Unreal is starting another process which **is** affected by `Alt+F4`ing but does not close my original process that I started. Thats why my launcher does not see the process closing (because it does not close). Well that sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so turns out the problem is the Unreal engine applications I am starting with my launcher. For some reason Unreal is starting two processes and only the second one is affected by `Alt+F4`.

Since the original process never closes my launcher can't detect it closing.

Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever for pointing me to the task manager. I don't know why I did not check before I posted here.